# Getting GooglePlus sign-in working with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So, I'm running into this error when trying to get GooglePlus sign-in working in my rails app:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Home#welcome

Showing /Users/user/Sites/new/app/views/users/_verifications.html.erb where line #22 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"passthru", :controller=>"users/omniauth_callbacks", :provider=>"googleplus"} missing required keys: [:provider]


<%= check_connection('Facebook')%>
<%= check_connection('LinkedIn')%>
<%= check_connection('Twitter')%>
<%= check_connection('GooglePlus')%> <----- this line is causing it.
```

**users_helper.rb check_connection method**

```
  def check_connection(provider)
    if current_user.has_connection_with(provider)
      link_to disconnect_path(social: provider.downcase) do
        content_tag :div, class: "verified-m #{provider.downcase}-verified row" do
          (content_tag :p, provider) +
          (content_tag :span, 'Verified', class: "verified")
        end
      end
    else
      link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(provider: provider.downcase) do
        content_tag :div, class: "verified-m #{provider.downcase}-verified row" do
          (content_tag :p, provider) +
          (content_tag :span, 'Click to verify', class: "un-verified")
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**Devise.rb**

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FR_FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FR_FACEBOOK_SECRET'], :scope => 'email,user_birthday'
  config.omniauth :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
  config.omniauth :linked_in, ENV['FR_LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['FR_LINKEDIN_SECRET'], :scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_network'
  config.omniauth :gplus, ENV['GPLUS_KEY'], ENV['GPLUS_SECRET'], scope: 'userinfo.email, userinfo.profile'
```

**Gemfile (relevant snippet)**

```
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'omniauth-gplus', '~> 1.0'
gem 'google-api-client', :require => 'google/api_client'
gem 'uuidtools'
```

And here is the relevant snippit from my OmniauthController, bare in mind, Twitte, Facebook, and LinkedIn validations are working - having trouble with GooglePlus only.

**OmniauthController (relevant snippet)**

```
    class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

      require 'uuidtools'

      def facebook
        oauthorize "Facebook"
      end

      def twitter
        oauthorize "Twitter"
      end

      def linkedin
        oauthorize "LinkedIn"
      end

      def google_plus
        oauthorize "GooglePlus"
      end

private

  def oauthorize(kind)
    @user = find_for_ouath(kind, env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    if @user
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => kind
      session["devise.#{kind.downcase}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    end
  end

  def find_for_ouath(provider, access_token, resource=nil)
    user, email, name, uid, auth_attr = nil, nil, nil, {}
    case provider
      when "Facebook"
        uid = access_token['uid']
        email = access_token['info']['email']
        auth_attr = { :uid => uid, :token => access_token['credentials']['token'],
          :secret => nil, :first_name => access_token['info']['first_name'],
          :last_name => access_token['info']['last_name'], :name => access_token['info']['name'],
          :link => access_token['extra']['raw_info']['link'] }
      when "Twitter"
        uid = access_token['extra']['raw_info']['id']
        name = access_token['extra']['raw_info']['name']
        auth_attr = { :uid => uid, :token => access_token['credentials']['token'],
          :secret => access_token['credentials']['secret'], :first_name => access_token['info']['first_name'],
          :last_name => access_token['info']['last_name'], :name => name,
          :link => "http://twitter.com/#{name}" }
      when 'LinkedIn'
        uid = access_token['uid']
        name = access_token['info']['name']
        auth_attr = { :uid => uid, :token => access_token['credentials']['token'],
          :secret => access_token['credentials']['secret'], :first_name => access_token['info']['first_name'],
          :last_name => access_token['info']['last_name'],
          :link => access_token['info']['public_profile_url'] }
       when 'Google+'
        uid = access_token['uid']
        name = access_token['info']['email']
        auth_attr = { :uid => uid, :token => access_token['credentials']['token'],
          :secret => access_token['credentials']['secret'], :first_name => access_token['info']['first_name'],
          :last_name => access_token['info']['last_name'],
          :link => access_token['info']['public_profile_url'] }
    else
      raise 'Provider #{provider} not handled'
    end
    if resource.nil?
      if email
        user = find_for_oauth_by_email(email, resource)
      elsif uid && name
        user = find_for_oauth_by_uid(uid, resource)
        if user.nil?
          user = find_for_oauth_by_name(name, resource)
        end
      end
    else
      user = resource
    end

    auth = user.authorizations.find_by_provider(provider)
    if auth.nil?
      auth = user.authorizations.build(:provider => provider)
      user.authorizations << auth
    end
    auth.update_attributes auth_attr

    return user
  end
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in making url
Try using:

```
<%= check_connection('GPlus')%>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it's still returning the same error even when I make  that change. What could it be? Cheers.